# JWT tokens: questions best practices and risk of symmetric keys

Tags: security, jwt

First a little background on my use of JWT tokens.

Users (via a web frontend) login to my service through a login HTTP endpoint that includes a username and a password in the request body. Two factor authentication will be added in the future, but can be ignored for now.

The API verifies the login information and issues a JWT token in the response. This token is signed with a symmetric key and includes a userId (UUID) that uniquely identifies the user.

In subsequent API calls, the user includes that token in the Authorization HTTP header as a bearer token. The API verfies the signature of the token and then uses the userId to make sure that the user is authorized by checking the roles of the user (stored in a database).

The token can expire, forcing the user to login again, or they can use a refresh endpoint that verifies the token and issues a new one to bypass logging in each time the token would expire.

What are the best practices for JWT authentication/authorization? Are there flaws with my approach? Is there a risk of using symmetric keys here? I am open to suggestions on better approaches as well.

Comment: If you do a database lookup for roles anyway, why don't you just use a plain old session id, stored in a httponly cookie? It would be less complex and more secure. Also less fancy though, I understand...

Comment: @GaborLengyel Why would it be more secure? Aren't cookies more susceptible to CSRF attacks than bearer tokens?

Comment: But they are not susceptible to XSS if set as httpOnly, and XSS is a bigger risk in most cases. Also CSRF is fairly easy to prevent, while XSS is not. I'm not saying XSS is a bigger risk in every single case though, but it is in most cases, and only special ones are exceptions. Also less complexity (and maybe using your language's built in session facility) makes it more secure by itself.